# android hls - get current bit rate

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, android-video-player

I've developed a video stream application and using HTTP Live Streaming. I want to get information about currently playing video. is it possible ?

For example , i need current bitrate of HLS Video. It is so easy with IOS(getCurrentBitRate function) , is there something like that in Android ?

Waiting for your opinions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're talking about metadata, I'm having the same sort problem right now. There doesn't seem to be a way to use the MediaMetadataRetriever on HLS streams.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to this is no - there is no API to access the bit rate with the Android SDK.  There are 3rd party HLS libraries that can help expose this information and also backfill HLS functionality since it is so fragmented in Android.